# Sublime Auto Quotes behaviour non-standard in Stylus syntax

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, quotes, stylus, single-quotes

I hope this is really simple, but I still haven't found any solution. I used to type quotes in sublime like this:

1. I press: '
2. Editor inserts: 'caret'
3. I type something in quotes
4. I press: ' again
5. I get: 'text in quotes'caret

This works for every syntaxt except Stylus(Package installed for syntax support [Stylus](https://github.com/billymoon/Stylus)). Here it works like this:

1. I press: '
2. Editor inserts: 'caret'
3. I type something in quotes
4. I press: ' again
5. I get: 'text in quotes'caret'

Is it possible to fix such behavior without? It is really annoying to have such bug for only syntax. Same problem for double quotes too. I will be really really grateful, if you help me) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by removing {"key": "eol_selector"} from "context" array and adding another "key" that restricts rule only for stylus. Keybinding for this looks like:

```
{ "keys": ["'"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.stylus"},
    { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^'", "match_all": true },
  ]},
```